# Как подключить owl-carousel (browserify)?

Tags: javascript

```
var $ = require('jquery');
var owl = require('owl.carousel');
   module.exports = function(selector){
return $(selector).owlCarousel();
};

owl('.owl-carousel');
```

В консоли вижу ошибку вида : `bundle.js:11899 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'fn' of undefined`

Как правильно это нужно сделать?

Answer (score 1):

Разобрался, ребят если кто использует browserify и будет реквайрить плагины зависящие от jquery то в вашем главном файле напишите `global.jQuery = require('jquery');`

Comment: По моему опыту этого оказалось мало. Заработало только когда сделал `global.jQuery = global.$ = require('jquery');`